# Find a closed form for the number of divisors of $m$ that are relatively prime to $n$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $m,n$ be positive integers. Find a closed form for the number of divisors of $m$ that are relatively prime to $n$.

Let $m = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$, and let $\beta_i$ be the largest power of $p_i$ dividing $n$. Also let $N$ be the number of divisors of $m$ that are relatively prime to $n$. If $\beta_j \geq \alpha_j > 0$ or $\alpha_j \geq \beta_j > 0$ for some $j$, then divide $m$ by $p^{\alpha_j}$. Otherwise do nothing to $m$. The number of divisors of this new number formed will equal $N$, but I didn't see how to find the closed formula.

Answer (score 1):

Say $m$ has exactly $k$ distinct prime divisors which does not divide $n$ (say $k>0$).

Say the powers of those $k$ prime factors of $m$ in the prime factorization of $m$ be $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k$.

Then the number of divisors of $m$ which are co-prime to n is $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\dots(a_k+1)$.

If $k=0$ then the number of divisors of $m$ which are coprime to $n$ is 1.